# Excel: combining averageif and search formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a criteria range and want to check if the cells in that range are substrings of a larger string. Only then do I want to incorporate the corresponding values in the average. However, I cannot make use of the Search function, since it takes two arguments. I also cannot use the "*" method, because the cells in my criteria range are the substrings and not the superstrings.
Please help.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample to help us understand your issue better?

Comment: Pure narrative is a deterrent to others trying to help.
You could try showing a layout of what you have and what you mean to get.
Add what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variant of this:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND($H$5:$H$10,$I$2,1))),$I$5:$I$10))
```

This is checking if the values in column H are found within the value in cell `I2`. If they are, then the value from column I for the corresponding row is returned by `IF`. We then average all such rows.

[image]

The above formula is case-sensitive. Note that `TRING` is not included but `tring` is. If you want to make it case insensitive, you can use this:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND(LOWER($H$5:$H$10),LOWER($I$2),1))),$I$5:$I$10))
```